# Copy contents of field to all dynamically generated fields below it of type

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, copy, jquery-selectors

So I have a series of dynamically generated inputs using the following code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 16; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".GCSE_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-top: 5px;"><div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="Subject[]" class="form-control spec_one" id="GCSESubject[]" placeholder="Subject"></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" id="SubjectLevel[]" name="SubjectLevel[]" placeholder="GCSE?"></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><select name="GCSEGrade[]" id="SubjectGrade[]" class="form-control spec_one"><option value="A*">A*</option><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option><option value="c">C</option><option value="D">D</option><option value="E">E</option><option value="F">F</option><option value="g">G</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one gcse_year" id="GCSEYear[]" name="GCSEYear[]" placeholder="Year"></div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary cas_btn copy_gcse_all">C</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary close_btn remove_field">X</a></div>'); //add input box
            $
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

What I am trying to do is to create a function that will copy the value of GCSEYear[] (the input next to where the C button is clicked), and copy the value into all subsequent GCSEYear[] inputs that exist, but not all inputs of type GCSEYear[] (there maybe inputs before, not after, that I don't want changed).

The following code is an example but populates all fields of class gcse_year and not just the subsequent/next fields of that type.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[id^="copy_gcse_all"]').click(function(){
    $('.gcse_year input').val($(this).closest('div').find('.gcse_year input').val())
});
```

I realise this is a relatively simple thing to do but I should be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you require by placing a common class on the parent `div` you append on click of the `Add` button. You can then use `closest()` to select that `div`, and then `nextAll()` to get it's subsequent siblings before `find()` returns the GCSE year inputs you want to amend.

Here's a full working example with several other improvements to the logic:

```js
var max_fields = 16;
var $wrapper = $(".GCSE_wrap");
var $add_button = $(".add_field_button");

$add_button.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($wrapper.find('> div').length < max_fields) {
    $wrapper.append('<div style="margin-top: 5px;" class="wrapper-item"><div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" name="Subject[]" class="form-control spec_one" placeholder="Subject"></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one" name="SubjectLevel[]" placeholder="GCSE?"></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><select name="GCSEGrade[]"  class="form-control spec_one"><option value="A*">A*</option><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option><option value="c">C</option><option value="D">D</option><option value="E">E</option><option value="F">F</option><option value="g">G</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control  spec_one gcse_year" name="GCSEYear[]" placeholder="Year"></div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary cas_btn copy_gcse_all">C</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary close_btn remove_field">X</a></div>');
  }
});

$wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
}).on('click', '.copy_gcse_all', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $wrapperItem = $(this).closest('.wrapper-item');
  var year = $wrapperItem.find('.gcse_year').val();
  $wrapperItem.nextAll('.wrapper-item').find('.gcse_year').val(year);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_field_button">Add</button>
<div class="GCSE_wrap"></div>
```

Also note that I removed all the `id` attributes from the long HTML string you `append()`, as this results in multiple elements sharing the same `id` which is invalid HTML.

Comment: That was remarkably quick and remarkably helpful. My code was also broken and didn't work. Thank you Rory that was excellent.

Comment: No problem, glad to help